# Azure Media Service CreateWithHttpMessagesAsync - Operation returned an invalid status code: "BadRequest" -

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-media-services

I am using `Azure Media Services v3` with an `Azure Function v3` app and am running into an issue when trying to create a new job from an https url.

I have the following method in the `Azure Function` that submits a job.

```
private static async Task<Job> SubmitJobAsync(IAzureMediaServicesClient client, string transformNam, string jobName, string fileUrl) {
    JobInputHttp jobInput = new JobInputHttp(files: new [] { fileUrl });
    JobOutput[] jobOutputs = 
    {
        new JobOutputAsset(jobName)
    }

    Job job = await client.Jobs.CreateAsync(
        _resourceGroupName,
        _accountName,
        transformName,
        jobName,
        new Job
        {
            Input = jobInput,
            Outputs = jobOutputs
        },
        CancellationToken.None);

    return job;
}
```

It's failing on the line that actually creates the job `await client.Jobs.CreateAsync(...`
and is returning an exception with a message of:

> Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'

Stack Trace:

> at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media.JobsOperations.CreateWithHttpMessagesAsync(String resourceGroupName, String accountName, String transformName, String jobName, Job parameters, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media.JobsOperationsExtensions.CreateAsync(IJobsOperations operations, String resourceGroupName, String accountName, String transformName, String jobName, Job parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Any idea what this means or how I can further debug this?

Comment: Can you offer the code in your function? How do you invoke your method? Please show more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem comes from the fact that you did not create the Output Asset before creating the job.
Try to add these lines before the job creation :

```
string outputAssetName = jobName;

Asset outputAsset = await client.Assets.CreateOrUpdateAsync(_resourceGroupName, _accountName, outputAssetName, new Asset());

JobOutput[] jobOutputs = 
        {
            new JobOutputAsset(outputAssetName)
        }
```

See also :
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet-core-functions-integration/blob/master/LiveAndVodDRMOperationsV3/LiveAndVodDRMOperationsV3/VodFunctions/submit-job.cs

Comment: That's exactly what the issue was. I could've swore that the example I looked at didn't create an output asset before the job but maybe I just missed it. Regardless, thank you!

Comment: This worked for me too.  Fiddler trace revealed the additional error message "The Asset with the name 'myAsset' was not found under the Account with ID 'myaccountGuid'"